# Efficient file matching in Ruby with special characters in filenames

Tags: regex, ruby, file, pattern-matching, glob

I am developing a Ruby application that involves a large number of text files (numbering in the millions). Each of these files is referred to as a two-character string, which can include both regular alphanumeric characters and special characters. Here are a few examples:

File named **ab.txt** (no special characters)

File named **-b.txt** (the first character is a special character)

File named **%!.txt** (both characters are special characters)

I am faced with the task of efficiently selecting a subset of these files based on the input text. When the user enters a string of two characters, the application must select all files in all directories whose names correspond to that string.

I tried to use a regex pattern with glob to directly search for files of interest. For example, if the user enters **ab** as a string, I use `Dir.glob` function like `Dir.glob("data/*/ab.txt")` to directly search for **ab.txt** files. However, this approach doesn't work if the input string contains special characters. For example, if the input string is **-b**, `Dir.glob("data/*/-b.txt")` cannot successfully find **-b.txt** files.

So my question is: How can I effectively select files based on a two-character string, even if that string includes special characters? Note that because of the large number of files, methods that involve reading all file names into memory are inefficient. I am looking for a way that can immediately select the files I am interested in, similar to the way globbing works when file names do not include special characters.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the filename contains special regex characters, it is the target, not the regex. Its very hard to figure out what you're doing. Are you entering a string to be used as a regex to match the filename ? Or are you hard coding a regex ?  I.e, what do you mean by _`search term`_ ? Are you actually tring to use a regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [Find](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/stdlibs/find/Find.html) excels at:

```rb
require 'find'

files = []
pattern = '-b.txt'

Find.find('some/dir') do |path|
  next unless path.end_with? pattern
  files << path
end
```

after running that, `files` contains the file paths of all files within `some/dir` (or any of its subdirectories) that end with `-b.txt`.

I would avoid using regexs, shell-based tools, or globs because they specifically make special characters tricky to use. The nice thing about `Find` is that it gives you the full file path as a plain string and you can compare it to a plain string, so there is no special character handling involved at all.